# HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath is empty on production

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my development server `HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath` correctly returns the path, but on production it returns empty.

Why woudld this be?

I am using this to build URL's, and now in production a link doesn't work as it looks like:

```
http://section/page1.aspx
```

but it should be:

```
https://www.example.sub.com/section/page1.aspx
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: I don't think it should return the host name at all. [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.applicationpath.aspx), ApplicationPath returns the virtual path of the application. Which doesn't include the host.

Comment: @Vlad you are right, strange how it works on my development server (it doesn't appear to be using a virtual path).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ApplicationPath` property returns the path to the folder where the application is, and it doesn't include the domain name.

I imagine that you have put the application in a folder with the same name as the domain name in your development server. The property then returns the name of the folder, not the actual domain.

Answer (score 1):

pls try this

```
public static string RootURL {
get {
    var _with1 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
    return _with1.Url.Scheme + "://" + _with1.Url.Host + _with1.ApplicationPath;
}
```

}

use this function when you need root url with application path 
please try and let me know if you have problem.......